# Customization of the Facebook 'Like' button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is it possible to customize the Facebook "Like" button? I have a specific image that I want to use instead of the default button on Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

You can see here that the css modification of the like button is no longer possible.

http://web.archive.org/web/20110419195549/http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=236534

Comment: thank you for your answer
but still I can not use a custom button as an image of like

Comment: Correct, it is no longer possible.  Facebook intentionally removed it. If you read the link I gave, you would see that it is no longer possible.

Answer (score 0):

You set a color scheme to dark or light like this:

```
<div class="fb-like" (...) data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

However, Facebook Terms of Use don't allow to put a customized Facebook button image. It is obviously possible but apart from breaking their TOS you have no guarantee it'll work in the future.

Comment: thank you for your answer

that there is a solution as a share:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u